# how to check if div is a specific part of the page in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a website that is structured horizontally and has a metro look and feel. So when the user scrolls, the content shifts horizontally. If you don't understand what i mean, you can use the metro apps on windows 8 start menu as an example. Now i want help with this jquery, i need to add a class name "current" to the div that's at the beginning(not top but utmost left) of its parent div. I know that my description is a bit vague but any help will be greatly appreciated.

ok here is the html and jquery:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="arrows">
                <div id="left">
                    <a class="slider" href=".previous">
                        <img src="LeftArrow.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    <a class="slider" href=".next">
                        <img src="RightArrow.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentBox">
            <div class="box" style="background-color: blue;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: green;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: yellow;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: purple;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: orange;">
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color: blueviolet;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="script">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('body').niceScroll();

            var deck = new $.scrolldeck({
                buttons: '.slider',
                easing: 'easeInSine'
            });

            var tempWidth = 0;
            $('#contentBox .box').first().addClass('current');
            $('#contentBox .box').first().next().addClass('next');
            $('#contentBox .box').each(function () {
                tempWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
            });
            $('#contentBox').css({ 'width': tempWidth });                

            $('#right').click(function () {
                $('.previous').removeClass('previous');
                $('.current').addClass('previous');
                $('.current').removeClass('current');
                $('.next').addClass('current');
                $('.current').removeClass('next');
                $('.current').next().addClass('next');

            });

            $('#left').click(function () {
                if (!$('#contentBox .box').first().hasClass('current')) {
                    $('.next').removeClass('next');
                    $('.current').addClass('next');
                    $('.next').removeClass('current');
                    $('.previous').addClass('current');
                    $('.current').removeClass('previous');
                    $('.current').prev().addClass('previous');
                }
            });                
        </script>
    </div>
```

The div "#contentBox" has a width of 4000px and the divs inside have a width of 550px and are floated:left. I've currently written jquery code to make my arrows work. if u look at my jquery i kind of need the same but instead of when the arrows are clicked it should be depend on which div is at the beginning of the parent div "#contentBox", that div will be "current" the one to its left will be "previous" and the one to its right will be "next".
I hope the new info will help you guys understand what i want to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your description is vague. Post some HTML and point out which elements you want to modify. And post the code you tried to write to do this -- we're here to help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: till now what have you tried,share that code

Comment: Please post the HTML you have and any jQuery code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

html:

```
<div class="panel" style="float:left">
panel 1 here
</div>

<div class="panel" style="float:left">
panel 2 here
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    $('div.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $('div.panel:visible:first-child').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: please check my edited part of the description for a better explination